# Vue - Vite | Static svg assets

Tags: vue.js, svg, import, vuejs3, vite

In my Vue vite app, I am trying to use svg file as src attribute in  html element.

```
<img class="..." src="/src/assets/images/bg/main-banner.svg" alt="Background">
```

In development, it works as expected.
In production, the src attribute of the image is *[object Object]*. I tried every approach from [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string) , but none of these could fix the issue. I am using vite-svg-loader, so I can use svg files as Vue Components. Could this be somehow related to the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

#### With `vite-svg-loader`

`vite-svg-loader` causes `*.svg` to resolve as Vue components by default, which would be converted into a string for the `<img>.src` attribute, resulting in `[object Object]`.

To load the `*.svg` as a URL instead, you can either [configure the loader to import the `url` by default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader#user-content-default-import-config):

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svgLoader({
      defaultImport: 'url', 
    }),
  ],
})
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-img-src-to-svg-file-ruyyhc?file=vite.config.js)

...or use a [`url` import param](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader#user-content-url):

```html
                             
<img src="@/assets/logo.svg?url" />
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-img-src-to-svg-file-orjpzt?file=src%2FApp.vue)

#### Without `vite-svg-loader`

If you just want to get the `*.svg`'s URL, you actually don't need `vite-svg-loader`, as that's a built-in feature. Removing `vite-svg-loader` should resolve the issue:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
// import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader' ⛔️ delete

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    // svgLoader() ⛔️ delete
  ],
})
```

[demo 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-img-src-to-svg-file?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 3):

Try to import it as module then bind it to the `src` attribute :

```
import mainBanner from "~/assets/images/bg/main-banner.svg"

<img class="..." :src="mainBanner" alt="Background">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I wanted to import many banners, like `main-banner1.svg`, `main-banner2.svg`, and so on, so I tried

```
<img :src="`/src/assets/images/bg/main-banner${bannerId}.svg`" alt="Background">
```

but I had a problem when trying to re-use the banner with another view.

My solution was to move the svg file to the `public` folder and use the path as:

```
<img :src="`/main-banner${bannerId}.svg`" alt="Background">
```

Note that this also **prevents Vite from adding hashing to the file names**.

---

**Note**: It is also possible to organize everything in sub-folders in the `public` folder to use the original path.

```
<img :src="`/src/assets/images/bg/main-banner${bannerId}.svg`" alt="Background">
```